# How to create a delete method in nodejs(express) with sequelize(sqlite) as database

Tags: node.js, express

I have been trying yesterday and still continuing today to figure out how to create a nodejs delete method so I can delete data from database based on ID.

I have tried different code from google/youtube/stackoverflow etc but nothing has worked so far.

The error I have with this code is that `data.query` is not a function. Data is a variable on my code.

If anyone has any idea how to fix please help.

app.js

```js
app.delete('/zoom/:id', function(req, res) {
    data.query('delete from', [req.params.id]);
    res.render('deleted')
});
```

data.js

```js
var Data = sequelize.define('data', {
    subject: Sequelize.STRING,
    MEETINGID: Sequelize.STRING,
    Password: Sequelize.STRING
});
```

Comment: Someone gave you a dislike, I think it  is because of your missing code. Can you please paste your whole code block. Not just a route handler.

Comment: That is the whole code I have for the delete method, do you require the GET and POST, aswell?

Comment: For example where is the `data.` method coming from, What is your database code like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize `destroy` method seems like a suitable one. E.g.

```js
app.delete("/zoom/:id", function (req, res) {
  data.destroy({
    where: {
      // criteria
    },
  });
  res.render("deleted");
});
```

To set a criteria which i suitable for your situation, you will need to take a look at sequelize syntax. I found some examples and may be you can modify them to your needs. Depending on your database structure.

```js
where: {
   '$car.id$': 2
},

where: {
   furniture_type: 'leather'
},

where: {
    id: {
        $notLike: { $any: someValue }
    }
},
```

Comment: What am I supposed to put inside the `where`

Comment: @angels7 I pasted some examples of how to use sequelize where operator. I think you should definitely take a look at the docs to construct a query for your unique case